# How to convert bitrates to megabytes

Tags: java

I am grouping by ipaddress and date and have bitrate as column. I want to convert bitrate (3600) to MB.This is how i calculate but not sure if it correct.

```
  //5 is 5 seconds per every row. i need to add this for every row.
  seconds += 5;
  Megabytes+=(3600 * 5 * 1000); // result 18000000 kbits
```

How do i convert this to MB?

Comment: Note: A KiB is 1024 Bytes, a MiB is 1024 KiB. (Mi/Ki are used to differentiate from the SI K/M.)

Answer (score 0):

3600 bps = 450 bytes per second. 450*5 = 2.25 MB per row over 5 seconds. That is slow for raw communications but ok at server level when you consider parsing and other pre-processing needed to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, i managed to solve the problems and here it how i did it.

totbitrate+=(3600* 5 * 1000)/800000;